Using UUIDs with Spring Security ACL leads to NumberFormatException
I'm encountering an issue while using custom id classes/ UUIDs as identifiers in Spring Security ACL. I can successfully save the ids in the acl_class and acl_object_identity tables, but I run into a NumberFormatException when attempting to look them up. It seems the problem lies within the BasicLookupStrategy.
It seems to me this is a recurring problem as I found some related posts (although slightly older). However, none could solve my problem (e.g. How to use Spring Security ACL when my domain identifiers are of String type?, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/pull/6141, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/7978).
I looked up the documentation but couldn't find any help there either (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/acls.html)
Setup:
Spring Boot Version: 3.2.2
Database: PostgreSQL
(The database uses VARCHAR for object_id_identity)
Test Code:
public class DomainId implements Serializable { 
    private final UUID id;

    // Constructor and other methods...
}

public class SpringSecurityAclTest {

    public void testCreate() {
        var acl = aclService.createAcl(new ObjectIdentityImpl(DomainId.class, DomainId.random()));  
        // throws NumberFormatException. However, acl_class and acl_object_identity are persisted as expected with uuid in respective column
    }

    public void testRead() {
        var id = DomainId.of("fc357b06-7966-4045-8f81-c696db560807");
        var acl = aclService.readAclById(new ObjectIdentityImpl(DomainId.class, id));  
        // throws NumberFormatException
    }
}

Exception Stacktrace:
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value [02152c51-035f-40d0-8a4a-a39ac6288e51]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:47)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:182)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:165)
    at org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.AclClassIdUtils.convertToLong(AclClassIdUtils.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.AclClassIdUtils.identifierFrom(AclClassIdUtils.java:76)
    at org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.BasicLookupStrategy$ProcessResultSet.convertCurrentResultIntoObject(BasicLookupStrategy.java:580)
    at org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.BasicLookupStrategy$ProcessResultSet.extractData(BasicLookupStrategy.java:532)
    at org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.BasicLookupStrategy$ProcessResultSet.extractData(BasicLookupStrategy.java:504)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:733)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:658)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:723)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:754)
    at org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.BasicLookupStrategy.lookupObjectIdentities(BasicLookupStrategy.java:335)
    at org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.BasicLookupStrategy.readAclsById(BasicLookupStrategy.java:300)
    at org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.JdbcAclService.readAclsById(JdbcAclService.java:136)
    at org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.JdbcAclService.readAclById(JdbcAclService.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.JdbcAclService.readAclById(JdbcAclService.java:125)

ACL Configuration
@Configuration
public class ACLConfig {

    @Bean
    public LookupStrategy lookupStrategy() {
        BasicLookupStrategy basicLookupStrategy = new BasicLookupStrategy(
                dataSource,
                aclCache(),
                aclAuthorizationStrategy(),
                new ConsoleAuditLogger()
        );
        basicLookupStrategy.setPermissionFactory(permissionFactory());
        basicLookupStrategy.setAclClassIdSupported(true); 
        // basicLookupStrategy.setConversionService(); 
        //  as of my understanding not necessary as a uuid converter is provided by default since PR#6141 (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/pull/6141)

        return basicLookupStrategy; 
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcMutableAclService aclService() {
        JdbcMutableAclService jdbcMutableAclService = new JdbcMutableAclService(dataSource, lookupStrategy(), aclCache());
        jdbcMutableAclService.setSidIdentityQuery("SELECT currval('acl_sid_id_seq')");
        jdbcMutableAclService.setClassIdentityQuery("SELECT currval('acl_class_id_seq')");
        jdbcMutableAclService.setAclClassIdSupported(true); 
        return jdbcMutableAclService;
    }

    // Other configuration omitted for brevity
}

Questions:

What do I need to configure to ensure Spring Security ACL can handle UUIDs properly?
Are there any specific configurations or implementations I might be missing in the BasicLookupStrategy?
Should I be using a different approach for handling UUIDs with ACLs in Spring Security?

Any help or guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

i cant help you more than i suggest that if you look in your stacktrace you can that the JdbcTemplate executes a prepared statement, and then after that it goes through a series of functions that ultimatly throws the exception. I would place a debug point there and then start step debugging to resolve why Spring security ultimatly thinks it should parse this as a number.
